# "Open Data Types and Open Functions" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there an existing implementation of the `open` semantics defined in the paper [Open Data Types and Open Functions](http://www.andres-loeh.de/OpenDatatypes.pdf)? As a GHC extension, as Template Haskell, as part of some other Haskell compiler, as a preprocessor, etc. The paper was published in 2006, and it claims to be simple.

I need data extensibility for a few core types in a project I'm working on. But I don't want to lift every constructor of the open datum to a type, and every open function to a class.

Comment: AFAIK there's no existing implementation of open data types and functions in Haskell. I believe that the authors of the paper were going to implement a derivative of Haskell with open data types and open functions. Don't take my word for it though.

Answer (score 1):

While it is rather heavyweight compared to `open`, the usual approach for these sorts of things is to introduce a mechanism along the lines of the "a la carte" paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.101.4131